# iOS 13 requires double clicking home button to Apple Pay

Tags: apple-pay, ios, lockscreen, nfc

As the title suggests, iOS 13 somehow requires double clicking on the home button to open wallet and execute a payment.

This usually, almost always actually, unlocks the phone instead. And wallet doesn't open.

Is there a way to enable the previous way of just resting finger on home button without clicking?

Comment: I don’t recall the behaviour ever being any different

Comment: @Tetsujin check this post: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250717887   You used to be able to just rest your finger on the home button and it does the payment.

Comment: I’ve never used it that way. Always double click from sleep, so it’s not something I’ve ever tried.

Comment: It still works for me like that. However, the timing is definitely different with respect to the double-click on the home button. I used to prefer that method, for example when the card reader was placed in an awkward angle. But now it’s almost impossible to access wallet from locked screen, as the phone is unlocked instantly on the first click of the double-click.

Comment: I've come up with a working solution for now: While phone is locked, quickly double click and release finger from button -> apple wallet comes up instead of unlocking phone -> then just rest finger on fingerprint sensor to scan fingerprint. This has worked for me 100%. As for iPhone X and others without home buttons, I have no clue if they have any issues to begin with. @matli

Comment: @pnizzle, Doesn’t work for me, as Touch ID seems to be too fast (iPhone 8). I almost never manage to remove my finger quickly enough. The workaround that works beat for me is to first unlock the phone, then swipe down from the top and then double-click the home button. This is quite OK, since in most cases I’m already using my phone when waiting in line.